# Removing duplicate values from a horizontal row or string

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a dataset consisting of about 50,000 rows, each line (or cell) with values seperated with a comma.

```
item 1, item 2, item 1, item 1, item3, item 2, item 4, item3
```

the goal output is simply

```
item 1, item 2, item3, item 4
```

I can use excel, open office calc, notepad++, or any other freely available program (I found a javascript solution, however it was for a single string, attempting to run it 50,000 times either did not work, or would take way longer than I have, and I don't know enough JS to adjust it)

any suggestions on how to do this?

<*edited to note that some items will contain spaces*>

Comment: they would be, however that will not happen; I have edited the original statement to adjust that fact (when I added spaces, I missed item2 once)  It is perfectly OK for the script to assume they are seperate values; as that example will not exist in the dataset.

(in regards to deleted comment about item1 and item 1 being duplicates or not)

Comment: forgot to note; additional bonus super points to any output that puts them out in alphabetical order.

Comment: i have a VBA script for this, but on my work computer, i'll post it in 17 hours if noone else answer it sooner

Comment: sure thing; would be much appreciated! I have tried a few things, but they all lock up when dealing with a dataset this large, as many strings have 50-100 values, and its about 50k rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should get you started.  Turn off screenupdating and calculation to get better performance...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim arrItems, c As Range, y As Long
    Dim val

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100").Cells

        arrItems = Split(c.Value, ",")
        dict.RemoveAll
        For y = LBound(arrItems) To UBound(arrItems)
            val = Trim(arrItems(y))
            If Not dict.exists(val) Then dict.Add val, 1
        Next y

        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(ArraySort(dict.keys), ",")

    Next c

End Sub
```

For sorting the keys:

```
Function ArraySort(MyArray As Variant)

    Dim First           As Integer
    Dim Last            As Integer
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim j               As Integer
    Dim Temp

    First = LBound(MyArray)
    Last = UBound(MyArray)
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If MyArray(i) > MyArray(j) Then
                Temp = MyArray(j)
                MyArray(j) = MyArray(i)
                MyArray(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ArraySort = MyArray

End Function
```

Comment: worked wonderfully; would there be a good way for the output to be sorted alphabetically as well? Unfortunately I don't know any VB (I figured out to modify the range, and "," to ", "; but as for actually coding a new function; im clueless)

Comment: running this generates the error "User-Defined type not verified" or User-Defined type not defined" - a quick google search said it is references, what should be referenced to make this work properly (the sorting?)

Comment: I just retested the code from my answer and it works fine, so I don't know why you're seeing that error. Is there any other code in that workbook which might be causing the problem?  If you can't fix it I can send you a workbook with the working code.

Comment: let me try running it in a totally seperate workbook, and migrating my data to that real fast? will edit this reply shortly to post results

Comment: ArraySort is called from the other sub - it's not a worksheet function.  It's just there to sort the de-duplicated output from Tester.

Comment: hahaha, didn't notice that the first function was slightly edited too! - Thanks again Tim, appreciated a ton!